# ERROR: Module mpm_itk does not exist!

Tags: apache2, apache2.4

I am installing a certain integrated library management system named: **Koha**. I get stuck at this error:

```
ERROR: Module mpm_itk does not exist!
```

Installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

The output in /var/log/apache2/error.log.1 says:

```
[Sat Dec 10 13:04:14.506341 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1561] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

I don't know why apache2 has got this way, because previously it was okay. When I uninstalled then reinstalled, this error occurs.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The `mpm_itk` module can be installed by installing the `libapache2-mpm-itk` module with apt.

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mpm-itk
sudo a2enmod mpm_itk
sudo service apache2 restart
```

The last 2 commands enable the module and restart apache after you install it.

Comment: When I run:  `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mpm-itk` I get this output: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libapache2-mpm-itk is already the newest version.
libapache2-mpm-itk set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.` and when i try enabling the module the error still continues @Dan

Comment: How did you install apache, did you install with `apt-get` or through a different method? Can you edit into your question more details from the error log at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install apache2` and the output from log file reads: `[Sat Dec 10 13:04:14.506341 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1561] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down`@Dan